# How do you install dlib in vscode?

Tags: python, installation, dlib

I am working on a Project called stress detector for which I have to use the face recognition module. But Everytime I try to install dlib, it shows me the following error. I have already installed cmake but still it is showing me the same error.Can anyone help me to find out what I am doing wrong as I am new to python ?

```
    b9d\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.10', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
  Running setup.py clean for dlib
Failed to build dlib
Installing collected packages: dlib
  Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for dlib did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [61 lines of output]
```

Comment: What happens when you try to install via the terminal?

Comment: How did you installed the lib?

Comment: It Shows me the above error when I install via terminal @S3DEV

Comment: First I installed CMake using `pip install cmake` then after cmake was successfully installed then I tried to install dlib using the command `pip install dlib` but it shows me an error every time I run this command. @RodrigoLaguna